# JavaScript for loop for object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, for-loop

I'm using Express to 'capture' data. I'm using a put request. My request is
localhost:3000/units/10 , with the body being:

```
{    
    "relayon0" : 400,
    "relayoff0" : 400 
}
```

And my code is:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'plc'
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.put('/units/:id', function(req,res){

  var id = req.params.id;

  var relayon = [];
  var relayoff = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    relayon[i] = JSON.stringify(req.body.relayon + i);
    relay[i] = JSON.stringify(req.body.relayoff + i);
  }

  res.send(relayon[0]);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The response returns null.

Any ideas on what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is `req.body['relayon' + i]` and `req.body['relayoff' + i]`.

Requesting `req.body.relayon + i` results in value of `req.body.relayon` (which is undefined) being added with number, which results with `NaN`. Being stringified, it results with `"null"`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will be sure to mark the answer as correct!